# C++ find co_await awaitable result type

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-coroutine

I would like to know if it is possible to find the result type of co_await of an awaitable:
As it is not possible to use co_await in an unevaluated context, I cannot do

```
template<class Awaitable>
task<> f(Awaitable&& awaitable)
{
  using result_type = decltype(co_await awaitable);
}
```

Is there any way this can be done ?

The main purpose here is do determine wether or not the result_type is void, here is basically what we have: we would like to fire_and_forget a task, and call a method on completion, but because of void return type, it's not that easy

```
template<class Awaitable, class Success, class Failure >
detail::fire_and_forget_task call_async_then(Awaitable awaitable, Success success, Failure failure)
{
  try
  {
    using result_type = ??
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<void, result_t>)
    {
      co_await awaitable;
      success();
    }
    else
      success(co_await f);
  }
  catch(...)
  {
    failure(std::current_exception());
  }
}
```

Maybe there a simpler way to do it, but right now I don't think of any.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do this generally because `co_await`'s [coroutine machinery](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/coroutines) is in part dependent on the *promise type* for the function that invokes `co_await`. When a `co_await <expr>` is invoked, it will have to transform `<expr>` into an awaitable type. Part of that process involves asking the promise type for the coroutine to weigh in on this conversion if it so chooses. Since the promise type is defined by the signature of the coroutine, the result type of any `co_await <expr>` is therefore dependent on the signature of the function invoking it.

This is why `co_await` cannot be used in an unevaluated context; it's behavior is context-*dependent*.

Now, if you *know* that your promise type does not have `await_transform` (which you probably do know, since it's *your* promise type), then the result type is possible to compute. The awaitable type for `co_await <expr>` will just be the type of `<expr>`. This is then converted into an awaiter object via invoking `operator co_await` on the expression. That's a bit difficult to compute, as it could be invoked via a member function or a non-member operator call, so it's a tricky bit of metaprogramming.

Once you have the awaiter object type, you can get the return type of its `await_resume()`; this is the type of the `co_await <expr>` expression.

Answer (score 1):

Ok thanks a lot, now I understand the reason why `decltype(co_await awaitable)` is not allowed.
So if I unterstood you well, and if I take the pseudo code from https://lewissbaker.github.io/2017/11/17/understanding-operator-co-await to get the awaiter from the awaitable type (let's say I skip the non member operator for simplification), I can get the result like this (maybe there's something simpler I'm not that used to writing detection idoms):

```
#include <type_traits>

template< class, class = std::void_t<> >
struct has_co_await_operator : std::false_type
{};

template< class T >
struct has_co_await_operator< T, std::void_t< decltype(std::declval<T>().operator co_await()) > >
    : std::true_type
{};

template< class T >
constexpr bool has_co_await_operator_v = has_co_await_operator<T>::value;

template< class T >
struct get_awaiter : std::conditional< has_co_await_operator_v<T>, decltype(std::declval<T>().operator co_await()), T>
{};

template<class T>
using get_awaiter_t = typename get_awaiter<T>::type;

template<class Awaitable>
struct awaitable_result
{
    using type = decltype(std::declval<get_awaiter_t<Awaitable>>().await_resume());
};

template<class T>
using awaitable_result_t = typename awaitable_result<T>::type;
```

https://godbolt.org/z/dAVfVX

Does it seem ok to you ?